# How do I minify CSS classnames with Ember CLI?

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-cli

I looked through the [docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation) on how to do this but nothing turned up.

There's this:

> The compiled css-files are minified by broccoli-clean-css or
>   broccoli-csso, if it is installed locally

So I'm guessing it uses `broccoli-clean-css` by default which uses `clean-css`. I looked at both `clean-css` and `csso` and neither seem to have an option for mangling/minifying class names.

So I looked at how the React / Webpack folks [are doing it](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reducing-css-bundle-size-70-by-cutting-the-class-names-and-using-scope-isolation-625440de600b). They seem to use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) which relies on `post-css`.

As far as I can tell, Ember doesn't use PostCSS out of the box?

**Question: how can I get Ember CLI to mangle class names and remove useless classes/IDs like `.ember-view` and `#ember123`?**

My motivation for this is I want to cache SSR content in Redis but my Redis instance is filling up so I need smaller payloads.

Edit:

I'm using ember-component-css but it doesn't have support for [controlling all class names in a module](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-component-css/issues/6).

Looks like I'd have to migrate to [ember-css-modules](https://github.com/salsify/ember-css-modules) which has the `generateScopedName` config option.

Comment: I wouldn't consider your example classes and IDs useless. They are added by the framework you are using for a reason.

Comment: @jelhan what's the reason?

Comment: Could you please add your use case? I'm not quite sure if I understand why you want to remove these IDs and class names.

Comment: @jelhan the use case is given in the question: "My motivation for this is I want to cache SSR content in Redis but my Redis instance is filling up so I need smaller payloads.". I do SSR with FastBoot. But an SSR request is slow (avg. 1 second) so I use Redis caching to speed it up. But I have lots of pages in Redis and I don't want to buy a larger Redis instance, thus I need smaller payloads in Redis. A couple techniques to achieve this: 1. mangle classes, 2. remove pointless classes

Comment: I don't think anyone has implemented this. Feel free to be the first.